# How to remove cordova plugin from MobileFirst project

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a Mobile First project with Eclipse, how do I remove `Cordova` for android only or remove the `cordova` plugin for that particular project? I did tried to use the `cordova` plugin list command in the project but it always showing me this is not a `cordova-based` project. However, the `Cordova` are inside the

```
android\native\assets\www\default\worklight folder.
```

May see the attached screenshot for the project interface:

[image]

Could help to advise?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Cordova & MobileFirst are you using ? Also, curious why you'd want to remove a plugin

Comment: I am using Eclipse Luna with MobileFirst server plugin v7.1, cordova is auto included in the project when add new android environment. During the PenTest, they suggesting to remove cordova, so I need to know whether can remove the cordova plugin in these project setting or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [post](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/) on how to add a new plugin to a MobileFirst hybrid app. To remove a plugin, you have to do the reverse

- Remove the plugin from `www/default/worklight/plugins`
- Remove the plugin's entry from `cordova_plugins.js`

Remember that each time you rebuild your environment, these are added back, so similar to the Ant script provided in the aforementioned post, you'll have to write one script to remove these folders.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a standard Cordova project - you can't use the standard Cordova CLI commands. (You've got to migrate to MobileFirst 8.0 if you want standard Cordova support.) In 7.1, you use the Eclipse UI to add and remove plugins/platforms from your project.

-Paul Horan-